# Unbale to capturing packets with high-precision time stamp with go packet

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, gopacket

I am trying to capture the live packets from available interface. My code is developed in go lang and for capturing purpose, I am using google's go packet library.

I am able to capture packets but I am unable to get precise timestamp.

If I run the below command and see the timestamp in wireshark, I am getting accurate difference between timestamps.

```
tcpdump -i device0 -j adapter_unsynced -w captureOnMachine.pcap
```

But, If I generate tcp dump using go packet library there is no precision.

I looked over the internet about adapter_unsynced command and saw

```
 PCAP_TSTAMP_ADAPTER_UNSYNCED - adapter_unsynced
                 Time  stamp provided by the network adapter on which the cap-
                 ture is being done.  This is a high-precision time stamp;  it
                 is not synchronized with the host operating system's clock.
```

Can we get same setting in docker or go packet library.

Answer (score 0):

There is a warning for [pcap.OpenLive](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/gopacket@v1.1.19/pcap#OpenLive):

> Warning: this function supports only microsecond timestamps. For nanosecond resolution use an InactiveHandle.

An [InactiveHandle](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/google/gopacket@v1.1.19/pcap#InactiveHandle) sets the timestamp precision to nanosecond by default (see [the source code](https://github.com/google/gopacket/blob/a9779d139771f6a06fc983b18e0efd23ca30222f/pcap/pcap.go#L766)). But if the hardware or software cannot supply a higher-resolution timestamp, it will fallback to microsecond resolution. If you're sure that the timestamp source `adapter_unsynced` is supported by the device and supplies a higher-resolution timestamp, you can set the timestamp source like this:

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
)

func main() {
    inactive, err := pcap.NewInactiveHandle("device0")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not create: %v", err)
    }
    defer inactive.CleanUp()

    // Configure the inactive handle:
    // inactive.SetSnapLen
    // inactive.SetPromisc
    // inactive.SetTimeout

    if t, err := pcap.TimestampSourceFromString("adapter_unsynced"); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Supported timestamp types: %v", inactive.SupportedTimestamps())
    } else if err := inactive.SetTimestampSource(t); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Supported timestamp types: %v", inactive.SupportedTimestamps())
    }
    handle, err := inactive.Activate()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("PCAP Activate error:", err)
    }
    defer handle.Close()

    // use the handle ...
}
```